# Winter Bash 2015: Mystery Chickens and Formations of Stickmen

Tags: discussion, hats, winter-bash

In one the discussion threads we found a way to achieve a heart formation by double-clicking on the head of the stickmen. How to get the stickmen fighting again? What is the mystery behind the chickens? How do I invite them on my Winter Bash page?

Comment: See [accepted anser on The Quest for the Winter Chickens of the Bash](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270937/180230) for clues... *<:-)

Comment: @BennySkogberg I hope you noticed I followed the same patter as my even older question, "The Quest for the Winter Unicorn of the Bash"